# Sharing failed please try again only in WhatsApp (API23) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app in which i have added the feature of share and i have installed the plugin of native_share (https://pub.dev/packages/native_share#-readme-tab-) and also changed the target api from 18 to 23 when i run the code it was working fine in all social media apps present in my mobile device except whatsapp. Whenever i tried to select whatsapp it shows "sharing failed please try again" and goes back to the screen.I can only able to find the solution of native android not in flutter. Below is the code.

```
class ShareURL extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mediaUrl;

  ShareURL({
    this.mediaUrl,
  });
  @override
  _ShareURLState createState() => _ShareURLState(
    mediaUrl: this.mediaUrl,
  );
}

class _ShareURLState extends State<ShareURL> {
  final String mediaUrl;

  _ShareURLState({
    this.mediaUrl,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        //print(mediaUrl);
        NativeShare.share({'title':'Plugin example app','url':mediaUrl});
      },
      child: videoControlAction(
          icon: AppIcons.reply, label: "Share", size: 27),
    );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and use the following variables:

```
const phone = '+20123456789';
var whatsappUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone";
```

then implement it in an onPressed function:

```
onPressed: () async {
    if (await launcher.canLaunch(whatsappUrl)) {
        await launcher.launch(whatsappUrl);
    } else {
        _showDialog(
        context,
        title: 'Error',
        msg: 'Please make sure that you have whatsapp installed',
        );
    }
},
```